# Network traffic debugging - noticed a lot of traffic from different ports in my VM

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, network-traffic, port-scanning

I am on a quest to analyze high egress traffic from my VM. Analyzing iftop logs, I noticed that a lot of traffic is conducted from different ports of my VM such as  :42272,  :42292, :42294, :55166 etc.

Below is the capture of `iftop -P -t -L 10000 | grep "=>" |grep -v https`
I have masked my ip address as xx.xxx.x.x

```
  1 xx.xxx.x.x:ssh                           =>      142KB     67.8KB     67.8KB      542KB
 561 xx.xxx.x.x:42272                         =>       688B       172B       172B     1.34KB
 562 xx.xxx.x.x:42292                         =>       688B       172B       172B     1.34KB
 563 xx.xxx.x.x:42294                         =>       687B       172B       172B     1.34KB
 564 xx.xxx.x.x:55166                         =>         0B       172B       172B     1.34KB
 565 xx.xxx.x.x:42322                         =>       686B       172B       172B     1.34KB
 566 xx.xxx.x.x:42234                         =>         0B       171B       171B     1.34KB
 567 xx.xxx.x.x:42306                         =>       684B       171B       171B     1.33KB
 568 xx.xxx.x.x:42340                         =>       684B       171B       171B     1.33KB
 569 xx.xxx.x.x:55276                         =>         0B       171B       171B     1.34KB
 570 xx.xxx.x.x:42336                         =>       683B       171B       171B     1.33KB
 571 xx.xxx.x.x:42194                         =>         0B       171B       171B     1.33KB
 572 xx.xxx.x.x:55280                         =>         0B       171B       171B     1.33KB
 573 xx.xxx.x.x:42282                         =>       681B       170B       170B     1.33KB
 574 xx.xxx.x.x:55178                         =>         0B       170B       170B     1.33KB
 575 xx.xxx.x.x:42274                         =>       680B       170B       170B     1.33KB
 576 xx.xxx.x.x:42196                         =>         0B       170B       170B     1.32KB
```

I dont know what this traffic is. I think all the traffic to my VM should be through apache server (port 443) and a little bit from :22 for my ssh.

When I count the bytes sent through above ports, it is not much .. about 32KB/s but still if it is an attack, i would like to fix it.

So is this traffic for these suspicious ports legitimate? If not, what should be my next steps..

Comment: please provide actual examples, the output of your commands, log files, etc. We can't guess.

Comment: I have added the output of iftop showing the ports. I can add more details as needed. Not sure what should i add.